# Use azure file share smb with android file manager

Tags: android, azure

I have some about Android connect to Azure file share with smb problem.

English isn’t my native language. I apologize for my mistakes.

I would like use azure smb files share with my android phone, I already install app like X-plore File Manager that support smb protocol.

but when I keyin url, stroage account name and stroage account key, app return message "failed authentication".

That url, name and key I think it's correct because I also use in my Windows 10 FileExplore, and it's work.

I didn't open secure-transfer because android only support SMB2.

How can I solve this problem?

Edit:
when I using IOS to connect Azure SMB, there is no problem.
But Android third party application always can't connect, Please see I have try app below.

1. x-plore file manager
2. AndSMB (samba client)
3. File Manager Plus

[app return error message like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1nCM.png)

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?

Comment: No. I try another solution for share file, finally I didn't use smb protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of storage account key, we can be able to use SMB, and for this we need to enable Azure Active directory domain services, refer to [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-ad-ds-enable) for enabling AAD DS. For enabling this we need client machine, with help of storage key we can add to AAD DS.

Thanks to [9to5mac](https://9to5mac.com/2019/06/17/ios-13-beta-2-enables-smb-server-connectivity-in-the-files-app/) for the blog for enabling SMB connectivity in files app for IOS.

Also, we need to interact with third party application to connect with Android.

Comment: Thanks your answer, when I using IOS to connect , there is  no problem.
But Android third party application always can't connect,
Please see I have try app below.
1. x-plore file manager
2. AndSMB (samba client)
3. File Manager Plus